# Server Error in '/' Application. - The resource cannot be Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing, jquery-autocomplete

I am new to ASP.NET MVC 2. 
I do not understand why I am receiving this error.  Is there something missing that i'm not referencing correctly.

I'm trying to create a simple jquery autocomplete online search textbox and view the details of the person that i select

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using DOC_Kools.Models;

namespace DOC_Kools.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private KOOLSEntities _dataModel = new KOOLSEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();

        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult getAjaxResult(string q)
        {
            string searchResult = string.Empty;

            var offenders = (from o in _dataModel.OffenderSet
                             where o.LastName.Contains(q)
                             orderby o.LastName
                             select o).Take(10);

            foreach (Offender o in offenders)
            {
                searchResult += string.Format("{0}|r\n", o.LastName);
            }

            return Content(searchResult);
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm)
        {
            if (searchTerm == string.Empty)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                // if the search contains only one result return detials
                // otherwise a list
                var offenders = from o in _dataModel.OffenderSet
                                where o.LastName.Contains(searchTerm)
                                orderby o.LastName
                                select o;

                if (offenders.Count() == 0)
                {
                    return View("not found");
                }

                if (offenders.Count() > 1)
                {
                    return View("List", offenders);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Details",
                        new { id = offenders.First().SPN });
                }
            }
        }


        //
        // GET: /Home/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Create

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Home/Edit/5

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace DOC_Kools
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "OffenderSearch",
                "Offenders/Search/{searchTerm}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    searchTerm = ""
                }
                        );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "OffenderAjaxSearch",
                "Offenders/getAjaxResult/",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "getAjaxResult" }
                );


        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<DOC_Kools.Models.Offender>" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#searchTerm").autocomplete("/Offenders/getAjaxResult/");
     });

 </script>
    Home Page

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%= Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]) %></h2>


        <h2>Look for an offender</h2>

    <form action="/Offenders/Search" method="post" id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" name="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" value="" size="10" maxlength="30" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />

    </form>
    <br />



</asp:Content>
```

what do i have to do in order for the textbox search to display on the index page?
What else do i have to do for the autocomplete to function correctly.  i have the autocomplete.js & jquery.js added to the index.aspx view

Any help will be appreciated so that i can get this working.

Thanks!

Comment: This is the error message details
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Offenders/Search

Comment: Did you set your URL in your ajax calls correctly? I mean to point to your action...

Comment: I am not sure this is my first project with MVC 2, and not really familar with .NET. I'm thinking i don't have my route tables configured correctly which i included in the middle of the code above.  i'm somewhat confused with the Route tables in the Global page.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's the order of the routes in the global.asax ?
try and reverse the order. i think that it tries to find the right routes from first to last and in your case it always stopes at the first route which is:  "{controller}/{action}/{id}" ...

Comment: Ok danfromisrael, when i reversed the order the 1st and 3rd map route and i run the app.  Once i enter in a name and click search, it returns back to the search page with no information and asking me to enter another name to search..